# Unknown Error with page/feed - Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am unable to retrieve posts from a Facebook page via the Graph API.

This is the code I am using:

```
FB.api(

    '/'+account+'/feed', 
    { 
        access_token : options.facebook.access_token,
        limit: options.facebook.limit
    }, 
    function(response) {
        doThingsWithResponse(response);
    }
);
```

This is the error i am receiving:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

There seems to be a bug related to this:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/328424960681438/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that will work in the meantime:

```
FB.api(

    '/'+account+'/feed', 
    { 
        access_token : options.facebook.access_token,
        limit: options.facebook.adjustedLimit
    }, 
    function(response) {

        if (response.error.code == 1){

            FB.api(

            '/'+account+'/promotable_posts', 
            { 
                access_token : options.facebook.access_token,
                limit: options.facebook.adjustedLimit
            }, 
            function(response) {
                Feed.facebook.utility.getPosts(response);
            });
        }

        else {
            Feed.facebook.utility.getPosts(response);
        }

    }
);
```

In the callback of the API call, I check if there was an error, and if so I change the call to `/promotable_posts` since that one seems to still be working correctly.

The one issue with this is that within `promotable_posts` I get posts like "Name commented on a photo."

So inside of `doThingsWithResponse()` I filter out those comments like so:

```
// reset adjustedLimit to base limit
options.facebook.adjustedLimit = options.facebook.limit;

response['data'].forEach(function(element) {

    if (!element.story || element.story.indexOf("commented on") == -1){
        // the post is worthwhile, so do things with it 
        doThingsWithPost(element);
    }
    else if (options.facebook.limit) {
        // increase the limit for each post that gets removed
        options.facebook.adjustedLimit++;
    }

});
```